# Alternative for nested loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nested-loops

I need an alternative for nested loops that take too much time complexity in my code.

I am relatively new to programming and am working with a code with the following data:

- `dates_list = ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-04', '2022-12-05', ... '2023-04-23', '2023-04-24', '2023-04-25']`
- a dataframe **df** with 30k rows and 3  columns: 'key', 'id', 'expiration_date'.
- an empty dataframe **time_machine**, with columns 'key', 'id', 'simulated_date' and 'status'.

I have already written a code that works well if I'm working with just the first 300 rows of **df**. However, the nested loop obviously makes it impossible to work with the complete dataframe **df**.
The original code has many if-elses and the dataframes have more columns to be analised, but I will omit them because they aren't really important to the nested loop issue.

I have run out of possibilities to solve this, does anyone know a possible alternative?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

file = '..\\Extrato.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file) #columns: "key", "id", "expiration_date"

time_machine = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["key", "id", "simulated_date", 'status'])

date_a = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1)
date_z = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = date_z - date_a

dates_list = [(date_z - datetime.timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(delta.days,-1,-1)]

for i in dates_list: 
    for j, row in df.iterrows():
        simulated_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        expiration_date = row['expiration_date'].date()
        if expiration_date <= simulated_date:
            new_row = {'key': row['key'],  'id': row['id'], 'simulated_date': simulated_date, 'status': 'ok',}
            time_machine = time_machine.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Look into this link regarding efficiency for nested for-loops: https://superfastpython.com/parallel-nested-for-loops-in-python/

Comment: you may specify what you're trying to achieve in your code better, because from what I see, you could achieve some of your code without the need to extract data from dataframes to lists. Pandas has  a lot of capabilities that lets you manipulate data and apply different functions .e.g. `df.apply`, and others that you can append columns, generated columns, etc. so why the need to work in arrays and loops, this way you don't make use of `pandas` as a data manipulation library.

Comment: You can use the [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) method.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```py
>>> time_machine = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["key", "id", "simulated_date", 'status'])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 'expiration_date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-06-01', '2023-01-01']})
>>> df
    key   id expiration_date
0  key1  id1      2022-01-01
1  key2  id2      2022-06-01
2  key3  id3      2023-01-01
>>> data_list = ['2022-02-12', '2023-01-01', '2023-05-01']
```

To make the code as fast as possible, you need to reduce the use of loops, and using datetime types may help (we will be able to use datetime operations):

```
data_list = pd.to_datetime(data_list)
df['expiration_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['expiration_date'])
```

If you sort `df` by date, the inner loop can be dramatically reduced (there will not be need to do the if statement that many times).

```py
>>> df = df.sort_values('expiration_date')
```

Now, we only need to use the outer loop.

```py
>>> for data in data_list:
...     # There is no need to do a loop to look at each one individually.
...     # As df is sorted, we also now that `values` will be also sorted.
...     values = df.loc[df['expiration_date'] <= data]
...     rows = {
...             'key': values['key'].to_list(),
...             'id': values['id'].to_list(),
...             'simulated_date': [data]*len(values),
...             'status': 'ok',
...     }
...     time_machine = pd.concat(time_machine, pd.DataFrame(rows))
>>> time_machine
    key   id simulated_date status
0  key1  id1     2022-02-12     ok
0  key1  id1     2023-01-01     ok
1  key2  id2     2023-01-01     ok
2  key3  id3     2023-01-01     ok
0  key1  id1     2023-05-01     ok
1  key2  id2     2023-05-01     ok
2  key3  id3     2023-05-01     ok
```